# number question

Tags: formatting, numbering, indexing, counters

I'm trying to figure out how I can make numbers in my index sort in ascending order, right now 11 is sorting between 1 and 2, i'm trying to make it come after 9 and 10.  I could add a 0 before the single digits, but I don't like how that looks.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{imakeidx}
\makeindex[name=bygrade,title={Routes by Grade}, intoc]

\title{test}
\author{oleary.brian1 }
\date{May 2019}

\begin{document}

\maketitle





%Add the index package

\vskip 2mm
\begin{minipage}{\columnwidth}
\item\textbf{place holder} \hfill M1 \index[bygrade]{\textbf{\Large{\underline{M01}}}! place holder} \par\emph{Blank space} \par Description Here
\end{minipage}

\vskip 2mm
\begin{minipage}{\columnwidth}
\item\textbf{Route} \hfill M11 \index[bygrade]{\textbf{\Large{\underline{M11}}}! Route} \par\emph{Blank space} \par Description Here
\end{minipage}

\vskip 2mm
\begin{minipage}{\columnwidth}
\item\textbf{Blank Space} \hfill M7 \index[bygrade]{\textbf{\Large{\underline{M07}}}! Blank space} \par\emph{Blank space} \par Description Here
\end{minipage}

\printindex[bygrade]
\enddocument

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can always force a particular sorting by using

```
\index[<name>]{<sorting string>@<index entry>}
```

MakeIndex will sort numbers before letters and will respect the natural ordering, so `7` will come before `11`.

Thus

```
\index[bygrade]{7@\textbf{...M7...}}
```

will do.